# Multiple $.post's?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post, woocommerce

I'm trying to add 2 woocommerce products to cart within one function using two $.post request. However, in the end only on of the products is added to cart. How can I make 2 posts at the same time?

```
jQuery.post('http://URL1/', formData1);
jQuery.post('http://URL2/', formData2);
```

Comment: Which one is getting added?  First one or second one?  seems like issue with your server side code. If you can't make changes at server-side code then execute second request in success handler of first request.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using the code from the answer below, with the second post in the first success handler, and a redirect in the second post success handler. It works, but the request ends up loading waaaay to long. Any ideas to make it faster? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the default async is not working for you. Then try the sync method.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using the code from your answer, with the second post in the first success handler, and a redirect in the second post success handler. It works, but the request ends up loading waaaay to long. Any ideas to make it faster? :-)

Comment: I you are going to use the `async: false` method then you don't need to chain them like you stated you have done. Redirect with the second (last) ajax call. However you are not going to see any performance difference. Your best option is to extend the server side add_to_cart functionality and configure it to accept a array of products objects rather then just one product object.